# ViewController.Type does not have a member named

Tags: xcode, variables, swift, nstimer

Just a simple task, but I'm in trouble. Trying to make a different way but it fails.

[image]

How to init NSTimer with declared previously variable? Neither var nor let helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize properties that depend on each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The initial value of a property (in your case: `timer`) cannot depend on another property of the class (in your case: `interval`).

Therefore you have to move the assigment `timer = NSTimer(interval, ...)` into a *method* of the
class, e.g. into `viewDidLoad`. As a consequence, `timer` has to be defined as an
*optional* or *implicitly unwrapped optional*.

Note also that `Selector(...)` takes a literal *string* as argument, not the method itself.

So this should work:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var interval : NSTimeInterval = 1.0
    var timer : NSTimer!

    func timerRedraw() {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: self, selector: Selector("timerRedraw"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        // ...
    }

    // Other methods ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var interval:NSTimeInterval = 1.0
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval, target: self, selector: "timerRedraw:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

pro-tip and hopefully an appreciated FYI: Swift functions should also start with lower case letters (i.e. "`timerRedraw`").

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. The same issue appears: interval not found

Comment: yeah, I forgot to note that you need to put your two variables into your "`viewDidLoad`" method.  Which is exactly what the other guy answering correctly said. I gave him a +1 for that.