# iOS: How can Objective C code read static variables in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

For Example, say if I have a class like so with a static variable pi.

```
let pi: Double = 3.1415926

 class MyClass {
// ...
 }
```

How can I allow Objective C code to use the static variable pi?
The projectName-Swift.h class will have auto generated code like so (just a small example and not 100 percent accurate).

```
  SWIFT_CLASS("_MyClass")
 @interface MyClass : NSObject
 - (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
 @end
```

So pi isn't being added to projectName-Swift.h. This is a small example on what is going on with my project and perhaps it should generate the static variable and I am missing something. Any tips or suggestions to fix this or make this work will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a class method to expose the static variables for your use case?

Comment: I will have to modify the Objective c code, but I guess it could work just fine.  Also, you mean something like this?  class var pi : Double {
    return  3.1415926
}

Comment: You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918628/how-to-define-static-constant-in-a-class-in-swift  This goes down the path suggested by JRG, especially Martin's answer

Answer (score 30):

You can't access Swift global variables on Objective C.

> You’ll have access to anything within a class or protocol that’s
>   marked with the @objc attribute as long as it’s compatible with
>   Objective-C. **This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed
>   here**:
>
> - Generics
> - Tuples
> - Enumerations defined in Swift
> - Structures defined in Swift
> - Top-level functions defined in Swift
> - **Global variables defined in Swift**
> - Typealiases defined in Swift
> - Swift-style variadics
> - Nested types
> - Curried functions

[Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_86)

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173234/how-to-use-swift-struct-in-objective-c?answertab=votes#tab-top) too.

Comment: (xCode 7.3.1) Looks like that `@objc` is not needed anymore.
Also, a root class can't be accessed from Objective-C, you have to inherit `NSObject`

Answer (score 2):

I would make pi static and put it inside MyClass. Also add @objc infront of each of them like this.

```
@objc class MyClass { 
    @objc static let pi = 3.14
}
```

Then in your objective C code you can call it like this

```
CGFloat piValue = MyClass.pi;
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to indicate that they are public

```
@objc public class MyClass { 
    @objc public static let pi = 3.14
}
```