# How to place IBOutlets in a two dimensional array in swift?

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

I have some IBOutlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var r1c1: MyLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var r1c2: MyLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var r2c1: MyLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var r2c2: MyLabel!
```

I want to place them in a two dimensional array:

```
var grid: [[MyLabel]] = [[r1c1,r1c2],[r2c1,r2c2]]
```

But when I compile, Xcode gives the following error:

```
InterfaceController.type does not have a member named 'r1c1'
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is not the 2D array, but that the initialization of `grid` depends on other properties of the same class. You have to move the initialization to a *method*, e.g. viewDidLoad(). –  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other for an alternative solution.

Comment: @MartinR Can you explain how to use "lazy" as you suggested in the other answer ? I'm not sure how to do it since this is an array.

Comment: I closed the question as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855137/viewcontrol-type-does-not-have-a-member-named because I think it is the same problem. My answer to that question was to initialize the property in viewDidLoad.  I have added a link to an alternative solution, but I did not write the answer to that one. – I did not suggest anything but presented two different solutions and you can choose from one.

Comment: @MartinR I think you misunderstood. you are more knowledgeable than me, and I'm asking you how to do it. My English is not so good. I tried doing lazy like in that answer but I don't understand the syntax since this is an array. Can you suggest an answer ? I can't figure it out.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25856755/1187415 applied to your problem would be `lazy var grid: [[UILabel]] =  { [[self.r1c1,self.r1c2],[self.r2c1,self.r2c2]] }()`. – But the (updated) answer below works as well (that's essentially what I suggested in my answer to the "duplicate").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is just fine, but you have to put your array inside of local scope:

```
func printFirst() {
    var grid: [[MyLabel]] = [[r1c1,r1c2],[r2c1,r2c2]]
    println(grid[0][0]).text // or stringValue
}
```

Update

```
@IBOutlet weak var r1c1: MyLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var r1c2: MyLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var r2c1: MyLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var r2c2: MyLabel!

var grid = [[MyLabel]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    grid = [[r1c1,r1c2],[r2c1,r2c2]] 

}
```

Comment: But then how can I make the array available to other functions ?

Comment: Why did someone give you -1 ?

Comment: I dont know. You just make function that return your array, or you declare it in viewDidLoad if you use empty array.

Comment: MartinR claims that you should use "lazy". Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Martin R knows lot more of Swift than me, so he's probably right. Just put 'lazy' before 'var':

    lazy var grid = [[MyLabel]]()

Comment: That is pointless, since viewdidload needs to be called before the actually code is loaded anyway. I meant using lazy, and loading the code in one line, like "lazy var grid: [[MyLabel]] = [[r1c1,r1c2]] (doesn't work for me)

Comment: Ok, but what is wrong with my updated answer? I think it will work like you wanted.