# Cannot invoke scheduledTimer

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have this very simple code to trigger a timer:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(2), target: self, selector: "timerDidFire:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

However it's giving me:

```
Cannot invoke 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval' with an argument list of type '(Double, target: TestVC -> () -> TestVC, selector: String, userInfo: nil, repeats: Bool)'
```

Which doesn't make any sense, my arguments types match exactly the required ones.

Here's the function definition:

```
scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(ti: NSTimeInterval, target aTarget: AnyObject, selector aSelector: Selector, userInfo: AnyObject?, repeats yesOrNo: Bool) -> NSTimer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used in the initial value expression for a property

```
 class TestVC : UIViewController (

      var timer = ... some expression using `self` ...

      // ...
 }
```

`self` is *not* an instance of `TestVC`, but a "curried function" of the type

```
  TestVC -> () -> TestVC
```

and that's where the strange error message comes from. The instance itself is
not fully initialized at this point. This is similar to the
problem in [ViewController.Type does not have a member named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855137/viewcontrol-type-does-not-have-a-member-named), and the same solution can be applied here:

Declare the variable as an optional (or implicitly unwrapped optional)
and initialize it in some *method*, e.g. in `viewDidLoad`:

```
class TestVC: UIViewController {

    var timer : NSTimer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( ... )
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift's compiler errors are often really horrible. If they don't seem to make sense, it's probably because they don't.

When you get a compiler error that makes no sense, remember to translate it to "There's something wrong with this line. I have no idea what, so I'm going to make up something totally unrelated and report that."

Or just "Derp?"

My money is on your `timerDidFire` method. Post the function definition for that method.

Also, a class that receives NSTimer methods has to be an Objective-C class. Usually it's a UIViewController so you don't have to anything special since all view controllers inherit from NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

this is what works fine for me in Swift:

1)
var updateTimer: NSTimer?

2)
In viewDidLoad: 
updateTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(2), target: self, selector: Selector("updateB:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

3)
func updateB(timer:NSTimer!) {
  ...
}

Hope it helps ...