# self invocations in computed property

Tags: ios, swift, computed-properties

Why in earlier when we invoke self in a computed property like this example we would need to write lazy var but now we don't have to. why?

```
   let(lazy var in earlier times) pauseButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    let image = UIImage(named: "pause")
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.tintColor = .white
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePause), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
    }()
```

Comment: You still do, I just pasted your code into Xcode 9 wrapped around a class and it doesn't compile because it can't find `self`.

Comment: Just to make sure that I got it right, you mean `self.handlePause` is it correct?

Comment: @BrunoRocha I justed pasted this code snippet to Xcode 9, it works fine for me.

Comment: Where is this code located? Unless this code is being called inside an instance method/property, referencing `self` like this is impossible because this property will be created before the class itself.

If this is at the class's scope, are you sure it isn't just Xcode screwing up? I saw it happen a few times with this case...

Comment: @BrunoRocha I assume that what are you saying is right, this is what mentioned in Swift documentation: "If you use a closure to initialize a property, remember that the rest of the instance has not yet been initialized at the point that the closure is executed. This means that you cannot access any other property values from within your closure, even if those properties have default values. You also cannot use the implicit self property, or call any of the instance’s methods."; Actually this kind of confusing to me now :)

Comment: see [Are lazy vars in Swift computed more than once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26454812/5175709)

Comment: @AhmadF I was able to reproduce it now! I was getting the error because I had a pure class. By conforming it to NSObject (UIViewController) in your case I was able to make it compile. I have no idea why though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a *misunderstanding*, which is what you mentioned in the code snippet is *not* a computed property! it is just a *stored property* which has been initialized by a closure; [As mentioned in the Swift Initialization - 
Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID232):

> If a stored property’s default value requires some customization or
>   setup, you can use a *closure* or global function to provide a
>   customized default value for that property. Whenever a new instance of
>   the type that the property belongs to is initialized, the closure or
>   function is called, and its return value is assigned as the property’s
>   default value.

<sub>You could check: [Difference between computed property and property set with closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515805/difference-between-computed-property-and-property-set-with-closure).</sub>

Note that the closure of `pauseButton` will be executed without even using it, if you tried to check it (add a breakpoint in it), you will notice that. I assume this is *not* what are your expecting -and not what are you aiming to-, so you should declare it as `lazy var` instead of `let`.

**However,**

Referring to the same [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID232):

> If you use a closure to initialize a property, remember that the rest
>   of the instance has not yet been initialized at the point that the
>   closure is executed. This means that **you cannot access any other**
>   **property values from within your closure**, even if those properties
>   have default values. **You also cannot use the implicit** **`self`** **property**,
>   **or call any of the instance’s methods**.

Implying that:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let btnTitle = "pause"

    let pauseButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        let image = UIImage(named: btnTitle)
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePause), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    func handlePause() { }
}
```

Will gives an error on the `let image = UIImage(named: btnTitle)`:

[image]

That should also be applicable for any other instance member, for instance, if you would try to add `view.addSubview(button)` into the closure, you will get the same error for `view` instance member.

**But for a reason** (I have no idea why), working with selectors seems to be a special case, because `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePause), for: .touchUpInside)` worked fine for me (Xcode 9.0), nevertheless if you tried to add `self` to it, as:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handlePause), for: .touchUpInside)
```

you would get the following error:

[image]

Comment: You are amazing)  but it still opaque, but more clear 'opaque')  well maybe we can't use self.handlePause selector because (of course) the rest instance has not been initialized (even functions somehow do not maybe created or wrote to machine code or smith else) , nonetheless we can mention self in our addTarget method inside closure of stored property. I think(maybe it is wrong) class don't have to be initialized while it is used by addTarget method as target. Class can be aware that it is target without initialize its properties) maybe that?)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `button.addTarget` in a regular stored property, you won't get a compile-time error. But I'm pretty sure it is a bug. I experimentally realize that selectors in regular stored properties causes unpredictable results in iOS versions 14.2 and higher. The selector may be released or any other selector that is given in the stored property closure may be associated with the button. As result, tapping on a button may trigger an action that is intended to be triggered by another button.

To do not tussle with such issues, I stick to the old way and use `button.addTarget` only in lazy stored properties.