# Swift dictionary with String key and UIImageView as value

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to create a simple dictionary that holds String keys and UIImageView as values. I have UIImageView variables declared from the storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var image0: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!

var buttonImagePair: Dictionary<String,UIImageView> = ["button0":image0!, "button1":image1!]
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
'gameViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'image0'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I declared gameViewController as a class. It is called from the main page of the app (when a user clicks a button as a Triggered Segue) to load page 2 of the app.

```
class gameViewController: UIViewController
```

Comment: Exactly how are you utilizing instances of `gameViewController`?

Comment: The problem is that a property cannot be initialized using values of other properties. Here is another question about the same problem with a different solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/change-the-x-and-y-in-a-cgrectmake