# Swift constant that depends on another constant

Tags: ios, swift, constants

I'm attempting to create a constant that depends on another in the following way:

```
class Thingy {
 let paddingConstant = 13.0
 let paddingDict = ["padding": paddingConstant]
}
```

The bottom line gives me an error `"Thingy.Type does not have a member named 'paddingConstant'"`.

Is it possible to declare a constant that depends on another?

Comment: Yes thats possible. You need to make paddingDict read only computed property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize properties that depend on each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another solution is to declare this variable `lazy`. The advantage is that, unlike a calculated property, it does not perform the calculation every time you fetch its value; but the downside is that it cannot be a constant, unfortunately:

```
class Thingy {
    let paddingConstant = 13.0
    lazy var paddingDict : [String:Double] = 
        ["padding": self.paddingConstant]
}
```

I regard that limitation as a bug in the Swift language.

Answer (score 6):

You can move paddingDict to the init:

```
class Thingy {
    let paddingConstant = 13.0
    let paddingDict : [String: Double]
    init() {
        paddingDict = ["padding": paddingConstant]
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot assign a value to a constant in viewDidLoad

Comment: Aside from the `viewDidLoad` part, this is correct.

Comment: OK, thanks, guys. I'll delete that part! (I was obviously thinking about variables for that).

Comment: Then if you have more than one designated initializer, you cannot avoid duplicated code.

Answer (score 4):

You can populate an `instance constant property a` (at definition time) using the value of another `constant property b` if `b` is defined `static`.

```
class Thingy {
    static let paddingConstant = 13.0
    let paddingDict = ["padding": paddingConstant]
}
```

This is the direct answer to the error message you got:

> Thingy.Type does not have a member named 'paddingConstant'

Infact by making `paddingConstant` static, it becomes a `Type property`: part of `Thingy.Type`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As another solution you can use an outer struct for defining the constant (and other constants you might need):

```
struct Constants {
    static let paddingConstant = 13.0
}
```

and then use it in `Thingy` class:

```
class Thingy {
  let paddingDict = ["padding": Constants.paddingConstant]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats possible. You need to make paddingDict read only computed property

```
class Thingy {

    let paddingConstant = 13.0

    var paddingDict : [String : Double] {

        get {return ["padding": paddingConstant] }
    }
}
```

Comment: however this will create a dictionary on every use of paddingDict

Comment: No it wont create a dictionary on every use, but will compute its value on every use and since your paddingDice use another property to compute its value it should be a computed property  . You can learn more about computed properties here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254

Comment: @zellb Can you show where that's explicitly stated?  If the property is computed every time, one step of that computation is creating a dictionary.

Comment: Creating new instance mean allocating some memory. Computed properties allocate memory once only and use that memory only for further calculations and thats make a difference

Comment: @zellb then it was also possible to declare it with 'let' which is more reasonable to indicate a one time memory allocation. But computed properties by their nature change and how exactly can it know if it needs further calculation?

Comment: It would have been nice if swift kept static variables in functions.