# my class does not have a member property

Tags: swift

My xcode version is 6.3.2. I ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/25856755/685060. I had use `lazy` but tell me my class does not have this member. Can I use this method? or should I need create a function to return appDelegate and lazy to call it? Thanks your help.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, DetailViewControllerProtocol {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    lazy var managedContext = self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext // This line
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but try the code below:

```
lazy var managedContext:NSManagedObjectContext = { 
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate    
    return appDelegate.managedObjectContext! 
}()
```

I hope it solve your problem!

Comment: @lighter Sorry I am not in my mac, do you wanna try the one I just update?

Comment: I try and I got a new error `unable to infer closure type in the current context`

Comment: I fix it, and it my answer, `lazy var managedContext:NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    }()` let you to update your answer.

Comment: @lighter Updated! I was doing it in my windows computer I can't believe I forgot to initialize "()" and to put the type "NSManagedObjectContext". Glad you was able to fix it. Good lucky with your app!