# Cannot create Struct with CGRect based on super.view.frame

Tags: swift, struct, cgrect

I'm trying to create a lookup of `CGRect` objects but I'm hitting a roadblock.

If I were to initialise a `CGRect` in `viewDidLoad()` it would look something like:

```
let myRect = CGRect(x: (view.frame.width / 2) - 50, y: (view.frame.height / 2) - 50, width: 100, height: 100)
```

but if that is within a Struct it flags:

```
'mainViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'view'
```

It would seem that I'm going about this the wrong way, so could someone shed some light on a better way to implement what I'm after?

Thanks very much.

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil No, it can't. You can't access `self` (implicitly or explicitly) in the initialization of a stored property on a class/struct.

Comment: Post the whole method that contains the problem code, and tell us where it's defined (as a member function of the view controller, as an initializer of a struct, etc.)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, that seems to be the problem! So I just need to create a method where I initialise the struct properties?

Comment: @SimonTheEngineer: There are different possible solutions. You can initialize the property in a method (in a view controller `viewDidLoad` is a good place) as in my answer, or define a lazy property as in matt's answer.