# Mapping array works in playground but not in Xcode project

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7-beta3

I am attempting to perform a simple mapping from one array into another.

It works perfectly in the playground, but fails in Xcode.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    let multiplicand = [1,2,3]
    var multiplier: Int = 3
    var product = multiplicand.map({$0 * multiplier})
```

The error message is on the last line

> 'ViewController Type' does not have a member named 'multiplicand'

Swift 2.0

Xcode 7 beta 3

Comment: Any reason you're not using the latest beta?

Comment: Can you post the code in the context you're using it in your Xcode project? Is it in a class?

Comment: @ Andy I am using this beta because that is the version used in the class I am following.

Comment: @ezig  It isn't in a class. It is an extremely  tiny project where I just wanted to test something (and failed).

Comment: @petegrif you should probably move '.map' call to an initializer or any instance method

Comment: @egor thanks, but why is that?

Comment: @petegrif take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25856755/1796907

Comment: @egor  thanks - got it. Makes total sense. Many thanks Egor.