# Swift - Xcode doesn't recognize existing member variables

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I have just started making a new game in Swift with SpriteKit, but it is coming up with an error telling me that the none of my member variables exist. I can't understand why it is doing this, because I clearly created the member variables.

Am I missing something?

Here is my current GameScene.swift:

[image: My current GameScene.swift]

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because, even though you specified a default value for `bluePortal`, at the time you specify a default value for `portal` no variable named `bluePortal` actually exists. Default values are values that will be assigned only when an actual instance of the class is created.
I suggest you create an `init()` method where you initialise `bluePortal`.

P.S. Next time, please paste your code instead of using a screenshot. It'll help other users troubleshoot your problem faster.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `var portal : SKSpriteNode! = SKSpriteNode(texture:bluePortal)` inside some method or just declare it above and use it inside some method.