# Instance member cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, random, arc4random

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {    

let fortuneArray = ["You will find true love in the summer.", "Outlook not good", "You may find great success in business soon.", "Watch out for grey cats."]
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(fortuneArray.count))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(fortuneArray.count)))
    print("random index: ")
    print(randomIndex)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// actions
@IBAction func cookiePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    fortune.text = fortuneArray[randomIndex]

}
```

I'm creating a very simple fortune telling app in Swift and I keep running into issues with `arc4random_uniform`.  Currently I'm just trying to get the app to draw a string at random but I get an error saying:

> Instance member 'fortuneArray' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

on the line where I am declaring the variable `randomIndex`.  I've been using google for awhile but haven't found a fix.  Hopefully someone can help, thanks!

*** Update ***
Problem solved!  Thanks.

Comment: are these lines inside a method like `viewDidLoad` or just defined in the class?

Comment: If Fonix's answer helped you, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the code you pasted is not defined in a method like `viewDidLoad`, you cannot use a variable thats defined at the class level for another variable thats defined at the class level as well. These variables are determined at run time and the order they are determined is not known so fortuneArray may not exist before randomIndex is made (might not really work like this behind the scenes but you can think of it this way at least)

you should compute these variables inside `viewDidLoad` or `init` or some other function instead

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  I'm using 'randomIndex' in an IBAction though.  Maybe I should have posted more of my code but if I declare the variable in viewDidLoad like you said, I can only use it within that scope, I believe.

Comment: Can you not declare variables `lazy` as described by Martin R in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: @Crashalot i think that only works in that case because the initial values of the variables used in the lazy loaded variable arent calculated at run time, im sure 2 lazy loaded variables would not be able to rely on each other in that fashion like in original question, since it would sort of be like a dependancy cycle. havnt tested it at all so maybe im wrong

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out with Fonix's help.  I declared the random number in an IBAction and that took care of it.