# Instance member cannot be used on type 'ViewController' in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to make an app in Xcode 9 using Swift and I'm trying to refresh the label display when battery level changes.

But everytime I use "label.text = value" I get an error that says Instance member 'LineTwo' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Here is my full code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var LineTwo: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

let observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange,
    object: nil, queue: nil) {_ in

        let msgOne = String(Int(UIDevice.current.batteryLevel*100))+"% ,Battery changed!"
        print(msgOne)
        LineTwo.text = msgOne //error:Instance member 'LineTwo' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'
        }
}
```

Comment: You're creating the observer outside of the `ViewController` class, so you need an object of `ViewController` to access this `LineTwo` object. Or simply move this code inside `ViewController` class

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012063/instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type-viewcontroller

Comment: Move your code inside `viewDidLoad`.  I would use `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryLevelChanged), name: .UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange, object: nil)` and then run your code inside `@objc func batteryLevelChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
        //
    }`

Comment: simply initialize observer inside viewDidLoad method, don't forget to user self.LineTwo inside the closure