# Instance member ...cannot be used on type ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

xCode Version 9.4.1

Hi,

I don't understand the error message given by Xcode console (despite many topic on this like this one :[Instance member cannot be used on type 'ViewController'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012063/instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type-viewcontroller)). Furthermore, when I have used "lazy var" in my code for ingStackView the  message disappears.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var tabStackView = [UIStackView]()
var nbIngStackView = UIStepper()


var ingCompleted : UITextField = {
    let text = UITextField()
    text.placeholder = "Ingrédient"
    text.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    return text
}()
var ingweight : UITextField = {
    let text = UITextField()
    text.placeholder = "Poids"
    text.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    return text
}()
var ingprice : UITextField = {
    let text = UITextField()
    text.placeholder = "Prix"
    text.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    return text
}()



var ingStackView : UIStackView = {
    var stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.backgroundColor = .red
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(ingCompleted)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(ingweight)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(ingprice)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return stackView ]()
    }
```

In front of :

```
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(ingCompleted)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(ingweight)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(ingprice)
```

> Instance member 'ingStackView' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize properties that depend on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer to the link you have provided explains this issue pretty well, IMHO. Basically, in your example, you are using the three "previously" declared `UITextField`s in your declaration of `ingStackView`. However, these four variables **are not necessarily determined in that order at runtime**. Xcode gives this error because, for example, `ingprice` may be determined after `ingStackView`. This is just an example, there is no guarantee in the order.

When you declare each of the variables with `lazy var`, the error goes away is because according to Apple's Swift Documentation:

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used. You indicate a lazy stored property by writing the lazy modifier before its declaration.

This means that for lazy variables, all of them are determined **at initialization**, so you are guaranteed to have all of the four variable values.

Comment: Thanks for your replying. I've perfectly understood. Is it better to use lazy var or to put `ingStackView`  in `viewdidload`?

Comment: Declaring `lazy` variables can be a more advanced concept. Putting `ingStackView` in `viewDidLoad()` can be easier to understand. It's up to you :)