# Save random alphanumeric string in Userdefaults

Tags: swift

i'm new to swift and i have a problem. How i can save randomly generated for each user alphanumeric string in user defaults?

```
    func randomString(of length: Int) -> String {
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        var s = ""
        for _ in 0 ..< length {
            s.append(letters.randomElement()!)
        }
        return s
    }
   
    static var keyS: Bool {
        get {
            return ((UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: randomString(of: 16)) != 0))
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: randomString(of: 16))
        }
    }
```

i tried this, but it didn't work. hope somebody can help me

Comment: Consider that you save an integer value for a random key. I suppose you mean the opposite.

Comment: i just want to save my random generated string, i'm new to programming so i didn't fully understand your answer(

Comment: You want to save random generated string for which key?

Comment: i think int key?

Comment: Suppose your name is "abcd", then you can save "abcd" for the key "name" or anything you want. You must need a key for saving anything in userDefaults.

Comment: so what's the key in my case?

Comment: Anything you want but you need to pass it as a string. Check my answer. Suppose you want to store a book list, then you can set "bookList" as the key. It is so that you can realize what you stored by this key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here "1" is your key for storing the random string. You can set it anything you want. Try this-

```
func randomString(of length: Int) -> String {
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        var s = ""
        for _ in 0 ..< length {
            s.append(letters.randomElement()!)
        }
        return s
    }
   
    static var keyS: Bool {
        get {
            return ((UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "1") != 0))
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(randomString(of: 16), forKey: "1")
        }
    }
```

Comment: it says "Instance member 'randomString' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'"

Comment: Check here and hope you can solve this simple problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34012230/14373360

Comment: thank uuu, it helped a lot. but i had to remove "static" will it affect to something?

Comment: Welcome. You can get a clear idea about the static variable here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53818259/14373360 then you will know if it affects or not. Happy programming.