# How to create an immutable array of struct instances as an instance variable in Swift?

Tags: swift

When I try to create the below `songs` array, I get the error:

> "Cannot use instance member 'song' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    struct Song {
        let title: String
    }
    let song = Song(title: "A")
    let songs = [song]
}
```

I can move `let songs = [song]` into `viewDidLoad()`, but then I can't access `songs` from other functions. I can change `let` to `var` and then change `songs` in `viewDidLoad()` to my array of songs, but then I've created a mutable array when I want it to be immutable.

How do I get an immutable array of songs available to all functions and still have each individual song available in its own constant as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize properties that depend on each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other)

Comment: That question is a bit of a different question and answers don't apply. I want an immutable array available to other functions. And I want the individual elements accessible by name too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating your songs array during initialization.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    struct Song {
        let title: String
    }
    let song = Song(title: "A")
    let songs : [Song]

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.songs = [self.song]
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know it was possible to assign a value to a constant later after declaring it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given that `song` is a constant, a simple solution would be just to make it a `static` property:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    struct Song {
        let title: String
    }
    static let song = Song(title: "A")
    let songs = [song]
}
```

If you need to access it within any instance methods, you can just say `ViewController.song`.

Answer (score 0):

For making an array of Song Type and add song you should:

```
var songs = [Song]()
```

And on view Did Load:

```
songs.append(song)
```

So it would be:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    struct Song {
        let title: String
    }
    let song = Song(title: "A")
    var songs = [song]

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        songs.append(song)

    }
}
```

Another Option to maintain it unmutable:

```
let unmutableSongs: [Song] = [Song(title: "A")]
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I don't want to make it a `var` because I want songs to be immutable.

Comment: Then you can do this: let unmutableSongs: [Song] = [Song(title: "A")] And it works!

Comment: Yes it works, but as I mentioned I also want access to the individual song constants through their names.

Comment: So accessing like this: unmutableSongs[0].title Doesn't work for what you need?