# How to add arrays inside variables to an array

Tags: swift

I have these arrays:

```
var inactiveLocationArray = [String]()
var activeLocationArray = [String]()
```

I would like to add them to an array like this:

```
let locationArrays: [[String]] = [self.inactiveLocationArray,self.activeLocationArray]
```

but it gives error:
Value of type (NSObject) -> () -> Controller has no member activeLocationArray

this actually works:

```
let locationArrays: [[String]] = [["test", "testas"]]
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize properties that depend on each other](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25854300/2976878)

Comment: You need to set the value of `locationArrays` after your VC has been loaded. When you declare it say `var locationArrays: [[String]]!`, then in `viewDidLoad` you can say `self.locationArrays = [inactiveLocationArray, activeLocationArray]`

Comment: @Pierce Or he could just make it `lazy`.

Comment: @Hamish - yeah that should work too, although I know in my experience I still have problems with the complier complaining.

Comment: thanks you pierce, thats perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code both compiles and works perfectly:

```
var inactiveLocationArray = [String]()
var activeLocationArray = [String]()
let locationArrays: [[String]] = [inactiveLocationArray,activeLocationArray]
```

Perhaps it doesn't do what you *expect* or *desire*, but it does work. The result is an array of arrays, precisely as expected.

> but it gives error: Value of type (NSObject) -> () -> Controller has no member activeLocationArray

That's because your code is in the *wrong place*. All executable code must be inside a function of some kind. Yours isn't. Example:

```
class Controller : NSObject {
    func someMethod() {
        var inactiveLocationArray = [String]()
        var activeLocationArray = [String]()
        let locationArrays: [[String]] = [inactiveLocationArray,activeLocationArray]
    }
}
```

If you move the `let locationArrays` line out of its containing method (here, `someMethod`), sure, it won't compile. But that has nothing to do with arrays. It has to do with the fact that the line is executable code, and cannot live off in the ether.