# Swift 2 Instance member 'circleIndexes' cannot be used on type 'GameScene'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I am making a rhythm app, but I can't seem to randomize the circles. Here is my code:

```
var alternator = 0
var fallTimer:NSTimer?
var flag:Bool = true

let circleIndexes = (0..<5).map { return NSNumber(integer: $0) }

let randomIndexes = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(circleIndexes) as! [Int]

func fallCircleWrapper() {

    if (flag == true) {
        self.alternator += 1
    } else {
        self.alternator -= 1
    }

    if (self.alternator == 0) {
        flag = true
    } else if (self.alternator == 5) {
        flag = false
    }

    self.hitAreaArray[randomIndexes[self.alternator]].emitNote(self.texture!)

}
```

The problem is with this line:

```
let randomIndexes = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(circleIndexes) as! [Int]
```

which gives the error "Instance member 'circleIndexes' cannot be used on type 'GameScene'". How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Are that properties of a *class?* In that case it would be a duplicate of [How to initialize properties that depend on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other).

Comment: Why are you using Swift 2 instead of 3 for a new app?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example that reproduces your error on a simpler scale:

```
func agePlusOne(_ num: Int) -> Int { return num + 1 }

class Cat {

  var age = 5
  var addedAge = agePlusOne(age) // ERROR!
}
```

You're trying to use a property /before/ it has been initialized... that is, before init() has finished, thus giving you a `self` to work with.

A way around this is to use `lazy` properties... lazy properties are initialized only when first called by an object.. that is, they are properly initialized only after there is a `self` available.

```
private(set) lazy var randomIndices: [Int] = {
GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(self.circleIndexes) as! [Int]
}()
```

computed and static properties are also lazy by default, without needing to use the keyword. Unfortunately, you cannot use `lazy let`, so the `private(set)` was added to give you more immutability, but not total.

PS, this is Swift3 so you may need to convert it to Swift2.