# How do I add a previous stated variable inside of a let command

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering how I could call upon previously stated variables inside of a let. I'm using Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002).

I have created a TableView which shows my players (bees) and current levels. I would like to be able to upgrade a specific player, without it affecting the other players.

Here is my current coding for the table view:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var beelevel = 0
var wasplevel = 0
var bumblebeelevel = 0

let bees = ["bee", "wasp", "bumblebee"]
let beeslevel = [beelevel, wasplevel, bumblebeelevel]
```

When I try using variables in the let command, it returns "Cannot use instance member 'bee level' within property initializer; property initializers before 'self' is available"

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25856755/1825618

Comment: Please [search on an error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Cannot+use+instance+member+within+property+initializer%3B+property+initializers+before+%27self%27+is+available) before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use instance member while declaring coz `self` have not fully init yet:

```
let beeslevel = [beelevel, wasplevel, bumblebeelevel]
```

But you can use computed property:

```
var beeslevel: [Int] {
    return [beelevel, wasplevel, bumblebeelevel]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared like that are not initialized in any specific order, so there's no way to be sure that `beeLevel` will be available when initializing `beesLevels`.

What you can do is override the initializers, there should be two for a `UIViewController`:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
}
```

Initialize your `beesLevels` constant in there and then call super.

PS. Just a heads up, even if you change the "levels" variables, you'll always get an array of 0s on your `beesLevels` array, because it's the value that's being stored, not a pointer to the variable.

If you want that array to always be up to date with those values you can declare it like this:

`var beesLevels: [Int] { return [beelevel, wasplevel, bumblebeelevel] }`

Comment: I'm new to swift so I'm not quite sure what you're insisting i do... Is there anyway you could possibly be clearer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use lazy initialization to achieve this:

```
 lazy var beeslevel:[Int] = [self.beelevel, self.wasplevel, self.bumblebeelevel]
```