# I can't use instance member array within property initializer

Tags: xcode

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Text1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Text2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Text3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!

    let array = ["Frodo", "sam", "wise", "gamgee"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count))) //Problem is here

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

        Label.text = array[randomIndex]
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize properties that depend on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't ask any question so I assume you have problem with accessing `count` of `array`.

In general you can't access any of instance members until init is completed. 
There are (at least) three solutions for your problem.

First is to override all `init` required by UIViewController and set `randomIndex` there.

Second is to use `lazy` for `randomIndex`:

```
lazy var randomIndex = {
    Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
}()
```

Third is to use some model (class/struct) for those data and inject it to ViewController

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the line to get the random index on the top level of the class.

It must be located **within** a function / method:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    Label.text = array[randomIndex]
}
```

---

And please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter (`text1`, `label`).