# What means this initializer property error?

Tags: swift, initialization

He guys, I know there are a lot of similar questions but the don't help me, so please give me a advice what is wrong/what I can do to solve this error

Declaration:

[image]

Usage of variables with the error:

[image]

Comment: Always post code as text and not as images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize properties that depend on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to use property values inside other property values, but properties are initialised before type `init` called, so instance is not ready yet, ie dependent properties might not be ready for such operation and compiler prevents such try.

The easiest solution for your case is to make dependent property `lazy`, because lazy will be initialised on first call, so instance is ready at that time:

```
lazy var TableViewDetailValues = [ ... ]
```

also it is possible to make it calculable:

```
var TableViewDetailValues: [String] { [ ... ] }
```