# How to completely hide a UITextView in swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, uilabel, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in a `UIView` that I would like the user to be able to show and hide by tapping on it. The `UITextView` and a constraint of 10 on each side. Currently when a user taps on the view the text does disappear, however you can still see where the `UITextView` is because there is about one line of space where the `UITextView` was.

Here is the code I use to adjust the visibility of the `UITextView`:

```
if(collapseArray[indexPath.row]){
    cell.noteText?.text = nil
}else{
    cell.noteText?.text = notesArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

I have tried setting the `.isHidden` attribute but I get the same results. I was able to get the desired result when I used a `UILabel` however I would like the text to be editable.

Here is what I am talking about

not hidden:
[image]

hidden:
[image]

As you can see there is still a large about of space below the word test, which is a `UILabel` that has constraints of 10 all the way around.

Here is the code I used for the given answer below:

```
class NoteTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var noteTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var noteText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!
    
    var textViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override class func awakeFromNib() {
        textViewHeightConstraint = noteText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        textViewHeightConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        textViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    }
}
```

however this gives me the error:

```
Instance member 'noteText' cannot be used on type 'NoteTableViewCell'
```

Comment: Hiding won't change the constraints, it will just make it invisible. You might be interested in a `UIStackView`. Else, you could use constraints to do so.

Comment: This looks like a TableView cell, correct? Is the cell built via XIB or is the layout done programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cell, hold a reference to height constraint of textView `var textViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`, probably in awakefromNib, be aware that constant is 0 and priority is low

```
        textViewHeightConstraint = noteText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        textViewHeightConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        textViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
```

In your logic, toggle the priority of constraint

```
if(collapseArray[indexPath.row]){
    cell.textViewHeightConstraint.priority = .required //this should set textView height to 0
}else{
    cell.textViewHeightConstraint.priority = .defaultLow //this should set it back
}
cell.textViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

**EDIT:**

As OP is facing issue with initializing constraint property in `awakeFromNib`, I am updating the answer below

```
class NoteTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var noteTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var noteText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!

    var textViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        textViewHeightConstraint = noteText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        textViewHeightConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        textViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    }
}
```

You are supposed to use `override func awakeFromNib()` not `override class func awakeFromNib()` also you are supposed to call `super.awakeFromNib()` before you go ahead and initialize your constraint, `super.awakeFromNib()` will ensure your `IBOutlets` are initialized by the time your first statement to initialize constraint executes.

Comment: I added the variable ```textViewHeightConstraint``` to my Cell class and initialized in the ```AwakeFromNib``` however, I got the error: ```Instance member 'noteText' cannot be used on type 'NoteTableViewCell'```

Comment: you must have made some syntactical mistake check again

Comment: This worked but instead of placing the initialization in ```awakeFromNib``` I placed it in ```cellForRowAt```

Comment: @david: Hey sorry It was late night here, so I couldnt reply, you shouldnt be initializing it in `cellForRowAt`, `cellForRowAt` gets called every time cell is scrolled, that means you will end up creating new constraints again and again for each cell, rather than creating constraint only once. `awakeFromNib` is called only once for each cell, that is the perfect place for adding such constraint. statement `textViewHeightConstraint = noteText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)` should be executed only once where as you should keep `cell.textViewHeightConstraint.priority =`

Comment: in `cellForRowAt`, hence I asked to place `textViewHeightConstraint = noteText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)` in awakefromnib where as the logic part (updating constraint priority `cell.textViewHeightConstraint.priority =`) should be placed in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: This is the problem I run into when I place the initialization in ```awakeFromNib```: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other. The given solution here does not work for me

Comment: Thats because you did not call `super.awakeFromNib`, call that first and then add your statements, also you have overridden a class func, you were supposed to override instance method

Comment: @david: Check the edited answer, and feel free to accept the answer back, once you test it works fine :) BTW question you mentioned and your problem though seem related they are not the same :)