# how can i pass a variable's value as a parameter to function?

Tags: swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var theme: Int = 1
    var emojis = getEmojis(theme)
```

theme can not pass to the function.***Cannot use instance member 'theme' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available***
i am not familiar to swift, when i code, i find that i can't pass a var's value to the function i wrote. plz help me.
i can pass 1 or 2 or 3 to the function, but i can't pass a var's value to function.

Comment: This is SwiftUI. You should add the SwiftUI tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do :)

If you're trying to initialize `emojis` to the value of `getEmojis`, but their values will differ in the future (you want to modify `emojis` independently of the value of `getEmojis`), use `lazy var`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var theme: Int = 1
    lazy var emojis = getEmojis(theme)
    // ...
}
```

If `emojis` should always hold the value of `getEmojis`, use a computed property, like @Raja Kishan pointed out

Answer (score -1):

Use computed property

```
var emojis: YourType {
    getEmojis(theme)
}
```

Currently, you are trying to initialize one emojis variable with another theme var at the time of initialization. You can't provide value for a second var property that depends on another var property.

Comment: thanks, it works. and i wonder if you are happy to tell me reason or give me some url about swift. thanks again, sincerely.

Comment: @YinYHuang added some info. you can also check from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25856755/14733292